# How to disable the Drag/drop action for parent in a TreeView model in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing a `TreeView` with drag and drop support. The desired behavior is to drag and drop only the children of the parents ("Parent-0", "Parent-1", and "Parent-2"). But in my current code, the parents can also be dragged and dropped, and this shouldn't happen.

[image]

Please run the codes to understand better what is happening.

Any ideas on how to implement this? I found on the web that this solution is related to the  `flags`, but I don't know how to implement it.

The parent and childs are inserted in the `void TreeModel::setupModelData()` function of the `TreeModel`.

Also, I have another issue similar to this. I would like to add a `ToolTip` with a custom description for all the children, but I don't know how to implement it. I found that there is a function called `setToolTip()` but my TreeNode objects do not have that attribute. Maybe
I should inherit from another class because I don't have these attributes.

These are the codes:

1. TreeModel.h

```
#ifndef TREEMODEL_H
#define TREEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QVariant>

class TreeNode;

class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TreeModel(const QStringList &modalities, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~TreeModel();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                      const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDragActions() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QStringList mimeTypes() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData* data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent) override;

private:
    TreeNode * nodeForIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void removeNode(TreeNode *node);
    void setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeNode *parent);

    TreeNode *m_rootNode;
};

#endif // TREEMODEL_H
```

2. TreeModel.cpp

```
#include "TreeNode.h"
#include "TreeModel.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDebug>

TreeModel::TreeModel(const QStringList &data, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    QStringList rootData;
    rootData << "Levels";
    m_rootNode = new TreeNode(rootData[0], 0);
    setupModelData(data, m_rootNode);
}

TreeModel::~TreeModel()
{
    delete m_rootNode;
}

int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return nodeForIndex(parent)->columnCount();
}

static const char s_treeNodeMimeType[] = "application/x-treenode";

//returns the mime type
QStringList TreeModel::mimeTypes() const
{
    return QStringList() << s_treeNodeMimeType;
}

//receives a list of model indexes list
QMimeData *TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray data; //a kind of RAW format for datas

    //QDataStream is independant on the OS or proc architecture
    //serialization of C++'s basic data types, like char, short, int, char *, etc.
    //Serialization of more complex data is accomplished
    //by breaking up the data into primitive units.
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QList<TreeNode *> nodes;

    //
    foreach (const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        TreeNode *node = nodeForIndex(index);
        if (!nodes.contains(node))
            nodes << node;
    }
    stream << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
    stream << nodes.count();
    foreach (TreeNode *node, nodes) {
        stream << reinterpret_cast<qlonglong>(node);
    }
    mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
    return mimeData;
}

bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *mimeData, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_ASSERT(action == Qt::MoveAction);
    Q_UNUSED(column);
    //test if the data type is the good one
    if (!mimeData->hasFormat(s_treeNodeMimeType)) {
        return false;
    }
    QByteArray data = mimeData->data(s_treeNodeMimeType);
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qint64 senderPid;
    stream >> senderPid;
    if (senderPid != QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) {
        // Let's not cast pointers that come from another process...
        return false;
    }
    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);
    Q_ASSERT(parentNode);
    int count;
    stream >> count;
    if (row == -1) {
        // valid index means: drop onto item. I chose that this should insert
        // a child item, because this is the only way to create the first child of an item...
        // This explains why Qt calls it parent: unless you just support replacing, this
        // is really the future parent of the dropped items.
        if (parent.isValid())
            row = 0;
        else
            // invalid index means: append at bottom, after last toplevel
            row = rowCount(parent);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Decode data from the QMimeData
        qlonglong nodePtr;
        stream >> nodePtr;
        TreeNode *node = reinterpret_cast<TreeNode *>(nodePtr);

        // Adjust destination row for the case of moving an item
        // within the same parent, to a position further down.
        // Its own removal will reduce the final row number by one.
        if (node->row() < row && parentNode == node->parentNode())
            --row;

        // Remove from old position
        removeNode(node);

        // Insert at new position
        //qDebug() << "Inserting into" << parent << row;
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
        parentNode->insertChild(row, node);
        endInsertRows();
        ++row;
    }
    return true;
}



Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDragActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeNode *node = nodeForIndex(index);
    return node->data(index.column());
}

Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
}

QVariant TreeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                               int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return m_rootNode->data(section);

    return QVariant();
}

//returns a pointer to the "index"
TreeNode * TreeModel::nodeForIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return m_rootNode;
    else
        return static_cast<TreeNode*>(index.internalPointer());
}

void TreeModel::removeNode(TreeNode *node)
{
    const int row = node->row();
    QModelIndex idx = createIndex(row, 0, node);
    beginRemoveRows(idx.parent(), row, row);
    node->parentNode()->removeChild(row);
    endRemoveRows();
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);

    TreeNode *childNode = parentNode->child(row);
    if (childNode)
        return createIndex(row, column, childNode);
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    TreeNode *childNode = nodeForIndex(index);
    if (childNode == m_rootNode)
        return QModelIndex();

    TreeNode *parentNode = childNode->parentNode();
    if (parentNode == m_rootNode)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentNode->row(), 0, parentNode);
}

int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;

    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);
    return parentNode->childCount();
}

Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

void TreeModel::setupModelData(const QStringList &data, TreeNode * parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        TreeNode *  node1 = new TreeNode("Parent-" + QString::number(i), parent);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            TreeNode *  node2 = new TreeNode("P-"+ QString::number(i) +"- Child - "+ QString::number(j), node1);
            node1->appendChild(node2);
        }
        parent->insertChild(i, node1);
    }
}
```

3. TreeNode.h

```
#include "TreeModel.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDebug>

TreeModel::TreeModel(const QStringList &data, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    QStringList rootData;
    rootData << "Levels";
    m_rootNode = new TreeNode(rootData[0], 0);
    setupModelData(data, m_rootNode);
}

TreeModel::~TreeModel()
{
    delete m_rootNode;
}

int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return nodeForIndex(parent)->columnCount();
}

static const char s_treeNodeMimeType[] = "application/x-treenode";

//returns the mime type
QStringList TreeModel::mimeTypes() const
{
    return QStringList() << s_treeNodeMimeType;
}

//receives a list of model indexes list
QMimeData *TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray data; //a kind of RAW format for datas

    //QDataStream is independant on the OS or proc architecture
    //serialization of C++'s basic data types, like char, short, int, char *, etc.
    //Serialization of more complex data is accomplished
    //by breaking up the data into primitive units.
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QList<TreeNode *> nodes;

    //
    foreach (const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        TreeNode *node = nodeForIndex(index);
        if (!nodes.contains(node))
            nodes << node;
    }
    stream << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
    stream << nodes.count();
    foreach (TreeNode *node, nodes) {
        stream << reinterpret_cast<qlonglong>(node);
    }
    mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
    return mimeData;
}

bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *mimeData, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_ASSERT(action == Qt::MoveAction);
    Q_UNUSED(column);
    //test if the data type is the good one
    if (!mimeData->hasFormat(s_treeNodeMimeType)) {
        return false;
    }
    QByteArray data = mimeData->data(s_treeNodeMimeType);
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qint64 senderPid;
    stream >> senderPid;
    if (senderPid != QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) {
        // Let's not cast pointers that come from another process...
        return false;
    }
    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);
    Q_ASSERT(parentNode);
    int count;
    stream >> count;
    if (row == -1) {
        // valid index means: drop onto item. I chose that this should insert
        // a child item, because this is the only way to create the first child of an item...
        // This explains why Qt calls it parent: unless you just support replacing, this
        // is really the future parent of the dropped items.
        if (parent.isValid())
            row = 0;
        else
            // invalid index means: append at bottom, after last toplevel
            row = rowCount(parent);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Decode data from the QMimeData
        qlonglong nodePtr;
        stream >> nodePtr;
        TreeNode *node = reinterpret_cast<TreeNode *>(nodePtr);

        // Adjust destination row for the case of moving an item
        // within the same parent, to a position further down.
        // Its own removal will reduce the final row number by one.
        if (node->row() < row && parentNode == node->parentNode())
            --row;

        // Remove from old position
        removeNode(node);

        // Insert at new position
        //qDebug() << "Inserting into" << parent << row;
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
        parentNode->insertChild(row, node);
        endInsertRows();
        ++row;
    }
    return true;
}



Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDragActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeNode *node = nodeForIndex(index);
    return node->data(index.column());
}

Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
}

QVariant TreeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                               int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return m_rootNode->data(section);

    return QVariant();
}

//returns a pointer to the "index"
TreeNode * TreeModel::nodeForIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return m_rootNode;
    else
        return static_cast<TreeNode*>(index.internalPointer());
}

void TreeModel::removeNode(TreeNode *node)
{
    const int row = node->row();
    QModelIndex idx = createIndex(row, 0, node);
    beginRemoveRows(idx.parent(), row, row);
    node->parentNode()->removeChild(row);
    endRemoveRows();
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);

    TreeNode *childNode = parentNode->child(row);
    if (childNode)
        return createIndex(row, column, childNode);
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    TreeNode *childNode = nodeForIndex(index);
    if (childNode == m_rootNode)
        return QModelIndex();

    TreeNode *parentNode = childNode->parentNode();
    if (parentNode == m_rootNode)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentNode->row(), 0, parentNode);
}

int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;

    TreeNode *parentNode = nodeForIndex(parent);
    return parentNode->childCount();
}

Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

void TreeModel::setupModelData(const QStringList &data, TreeNode * parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        TreeNode *  node1 = new TreeNode("Parent-" + QString::number(i), parent);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            TreeNode *  node2 = new TreeNode("P-"+ QString::number(i) +"- Child - "+ QString::number(j), node1);
            node1->appendChild(node2);
        }
        parent->insertChild(i, node1);
    }
}
```

4. TreeNode.cpp

```
#include <QStringList>

TreeNode::TreeNode(const QString &data, TreeNode *parent)
    : m_nodeData(data), m_parentNode(parent)
{
}

TreeNode::~TreeNode()
{
    qDeleteAll(m_childNodes);
}

void TreeNode::appendChild(TreeNode *node)
{
    m_childNodes.append(node);
}

void TreeNode::removeChild(int row)
{
    m_childNodes.removeAt(row);
}

TreeNode *TreeNode::child(int row) const
{
    return m_childNodes.value(row);
}

int TreeNode::childCount() const
{
    return m_childNodes.count();
}

int TreeNode::columnCount() const
{
    return m_nodeData.count();
}

QVariant TreeNode::data(int column) const
{
    return m_nodeData.value(column);
}

TreeNode *TreeNode::parentNode() const
{
    return m_parentNode;
}

int TreeNode::row() const
{
    if (m_parentNode)
        return m_parentNode->m_childNodes.indexOf(const_cast<TreeNode*>(this));

    return 0;
}

void TreeNode::insertChild(int pos, TreeNode *child)
{
    m_childNodes.insert(pos, child);
    child->m_parentNode = this;
}
```

5. TreeView.h

```
#define TREEVIEW_H

#include "TreeModel.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QTreeView>


class TreeView : public QTreeView
{
public:
    TreeView(TreeModel *model);
    TreeView();
    void setModel(TreeModel *model);
};

#endif // TREEVIEW_H
```

6. TreeView.cpp

```
#include "TreeModel.h"
#include <QHeaderView>

TreeView::TreeView(TreeModel *model)
{
    setModel(model);
    TreeView();
}

TreeView::TreeView()
{
    connect(this, &QTreeView::pressed, this, &QTreeView::expandAll);
    setDragEnabled(true);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    resizeColumnToContents(0);
    resize(400, 500);
    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    expandAll();
    connect(this, &QTreeView::pressed, this, &QTreeView::expandAll);
    header()->setVisible(false);
    setIndentation(5);
    setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers());
}



void TreeView::setModel(TreeModel* model)
{
    QItemSelectionModel* m = selectionModel();
    delete m;
    QTreeView::setModel(model);
}
```

7. main.cpp (This is just to run the project, just ignore the `QStringList data`)

```
#include "TreeView.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringList data;
    data.push_back("Item 1");
    TreeModel model(data);
    TreeView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Tree Model"));
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I use this post as a reference to implement drag and drop.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/76708/full-drag-and-drop-support-in-qtreeview

Comment: _But in my current code, the parents can also be dragged and dropped, and this shouldn't happen._ Please, have a look into your `TreeModel::flags()`. It returns `QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;` for _every valid_ `QModelIndex`. If you intend to make parents undraggable you need a more sophisticated logic here. [QAbstractItemModel::flags()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) and [Qt::ItemFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum): _`Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled` | 4 | **It can be dragged**._ (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff'sCat thanks for your reply. You're right, the conditions to make parents undraggable must be stablished in `QAbstractItemModel::flags()`, thanks. BTW, do you have any ideas on how to add a `ToolTip` (description when mouse hover a child of the tree) for the childs?. I think is a similar fix to the flags, I found out that the `toolTip` should be added in `TreeModel::data()` function using `Qt::ToolTipRole`. So, according to the web I can use something like this `if(role == Qt::ToolTipRole) { return "This is  a tooltip"}`,  but in my case the condition never is `true`.